# BehaviorSubject is not updating when assigned data from api response

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, behaviorsubject

I have user data service. Purpose of the data service is to broadcast user data and share data among different components. If one component makes the change to the user other components should know about it. It is working fine in other components. For example, I update location of user in Location component and its available everywhere. I have signin component where I am sending user credentials to API and receive user data. I assign received data to my broadcast user object but it doesnt reflect in my checkout component.

> ***user-data.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import {User} from '../entities/user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserDataService {
  private _user: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  broadCastUser: Observable<User>;

  constructor() {
    this._user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User());
    this.broadCastUser = this._user.asObservable();
  }

  updateUser (newUser) {
    this._user.next(newUser);
  }
}
```

> ***sign-in.component.ts***

```
// removing unnecessary code
private _user: User;
ngOnInit() {

    // Getting user info so far
    this._userDataService.broadCastUser.subscribe(user => this._user = user);
}


signin () {
    const body = {
      UserId : this.emailAddress.value,
      Password : this.password.value
    };

    this._spinner.show();

    this._signInService.signIn(body).subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this._spinner.hide();

        // Handling error because API response is 200 Ok. Wrong API implementation.
        const userId = user[0].UserId;
        if (userId === 0) {
          this._isPasswordWrong = true;
        } else {
        this._user = user[0];
        this._user.isSignedIn = true;
        this._router.navigate(['/checkout']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Please notice the line in sign in method ***this._user = user[0];***. If I print the user properties immidiately after this line then I see they are updated. But when I go to checkout component then they are not updated. They are either old values or undefined.

I will provide all the code if required. But feels this is enough.

Comment: Seems like you call the update-function outside of the NgZone, so Angular does not register changes and doesn't update the values in the component. From where do you call update?

Comment: @Leon i am not using update function anywhere. The local object is linked to BehaviorSubject object. Its working fine withoud update function everywhere else in app. I will read about NgZone and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is the ideal solution or not but the app is working the way it supposed to work.

I added private update method to ***sign-in.component.ts*** and call it inside ***signIn()*** in place of ***this._user = user[0];***

I took a hint from @Leon comments and came to this solution.

```
  signin () {
    const body = {
      UserId : this.emailAddress.value,
      Password : this.password.value
    };

    this._spinner.show();

    this._signInService.signIn(body).subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this._spinner.hide();

        // Handling error because API response is 200 Ok. Wrong API implementation.
        const userId = user[0].UserId;
        if (userId === 0) {
          this._isPasswordWrong = true;
        } else {
        this.updateUser (user[0]);
        this._router.navigate(['/checkout']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

> ***new update ()***

```
private updateUser (user: User) {
    let newUser = new User();
    newUser = user;
    newUser.cart = this._user.cart;
    newUser.address = this._user.address;
    newUser.isSignedIn = true;
    this._userDataService.updateUser(newUser);
  }
```

I am open and ready to accept a better answer. If I found one, I will post it here.